# Understanding total orders, strict total orders, and partial orders

Tags: relations, order-theory

In Rudin's book, he defines an order $<$ on a set $S$ as one satisfying transitivity ($x < y$ and $y < z$ implies $x < z$) and trichotomy (exactly one of $x <y$, $y < x$, and $x = y$) holds. I was under the impression that this is a total order because every element is comparable and Rudin never made a distinction between a partial order and a total order. However, a set of lecture videos I'm watching build up a total order from a partial order, defining it as one satisfying reflexivity ($xRx$ for all $x$), transitivity ($xRy$ and $yRz$ implies $xRz$), and antisymmetry ($xRy$ and $yRx$ implies $x = y$).

I'm trying to reconcile these two definitions in the context of the standard order $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The trichotomy condition seems to be close to antisymmetry, but only vacuously, because I can't have $x < y$ and $y < x$. If I "expand" $<$ to $\leq$, then I know $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$ implies $x = y$. Reflexivity is not satisfied in the case of $<$, but it is satisfied for $\leq$.

I can't say that $\leq$ is a total order because it fails trichotomy: I can't say exactly one of $x \leq y$, $y \leq x$, or $x = y$ holds because if $x = y$, then all three hold.
I did some more reading and found there is a such thing as a "strict" total order, which seems to be a total order in the precise sense of Rudin, but without reflexivity.

With all of these said, there are two things I would really appreciate someone clearing up for me:

(a) Which of these definitions of total order are standard? Do we need to specialize to a strict total order in the sense of Rudin for the standard order on $\mathbb{R}$?

(b) How do I reconcile $<$ and $\leq$ in this case? When I define an order $<$, is there a sense in which I can "specialize" to $\leq$? I believe $\leq$ is usually a partial order, but it is not a total order because of trichotomy.

Comment: $<$ is a strict total order. $\leq $ is a (weak) total order. An example of a partial order is set containment (subset): e.g. $S=\{a,b,c\}$. Then $\{ a, b \} \subset \{ a, b, c \}$, but $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c\}$ aren't comparable.  The lecture is talking about a (weak) total order. Rudin is talking about a strict total order.

Comment: @Mark Is the only difference between a weak and a strict total order the reflexivity property? It makes sense to me that it holds in the case of $\leq$ but not $<$, but I'm still trying to reconcile the trichotomy property, which seems similar to (but not exactly) the antisymmetry property.

Comment: The strict total order has no reflexive property, thus exactly one of the trichotomy is true; and yes it has the antisymmetric property. The (weak) total order has the reflexive property, which means the case of equality gives us all 3 parts of the trichotomy (thus it doesn't have that property); it lacks the antisymmetric property.

Comment: @Mark What do you mean with $\leq$ lacks the antisymmetric property? It's one of the defining properties of every partial order.

Comment: @amrsa Sorry, I think I meant that $<$ lacks the antisymmetric property. Certainly $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$ implies $x = y$.

Comment: @Cardinality The comment was to Mark. I suppose he meant just what you just wrote but got confused. Anyway, $<$ is also antisymmetric, vacuously as you point out in the post.